# Comparing medians of a variable between groups formed by two categorical variables

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multicollinearity, skewness, median

I hope my question makes sense. I have three variables: Two categorical with 4 levels in each and one numerical, ranging from 0 to 10. Now, I want to form groups based on the categorical variables and this can be achieved with cross tabulation. This forms 4x4 = 16 groups. For each of these groups, I want to calculate the medians for the third variable (medians because the data is skewed). I can do this quite easily in R and I have an observable difference, but I cannot figure out how to test the statistical significance of this difference.

Here is a table (from R using `ftable()`) with the number of observations in each group.

```
          categorical1           1   2   3   4
categorical2                                       
0                              104 121  77  26
1                               68  72  70  24
2                               19  26  28   8
3-4                              4   9   8   9
```

Next I have calculated the median of the third variable in each group, so for example there are 24 observations in the group where categorical1 = 4 and categorical2 = 1. Of these 24 observations the median of the third variable is 7.0, as can be seen in this table:

[image]

As we can see, it appears as though the median grows when we go from left to right, but not when we go from top to bottom (the latter would actually be expected, which is why I'm very interested in this finding).

My question: how do I test the statistical significance of the difference in medians between the 16 groups?

Note: I don't think I can use logistic regression, because there is severe multicollinearity between variables.
Also I probably can't use discriminant analysis because the data is skewed.

Comment: As first steps, you could test whether there is a significant difference between medians for a) categorical1 = 1 or 2 and b) categorical1 = 3 or 4; and then run the same test restricted to each of the values of categorical2

Comment: Thanks. I ended up calculating the p-values for each column and each row separately using Kruskal-Wallis test. It's still not exactly what I had in mind but at least tells something.